# SQL Найти максимальную сумму в таблице

Tags: sql, mysql

Есть таблица, как вывести максимальную сумму по какому-либо параметру? СУБД mySQL

Например такая таблица

```
|id|par|  
|1 | 2 |
|1 | 6 |
|2 | 2 |
|2 | 1 |
```

Получить такой id, у которого сумма всех par максимальна.

Comment: ?

       select id, sum(par) as par from t group by id order by par desc limit 1;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Стандартное решение, которое даст правильный результат, если максимум достигается для нескольких id:

```
select id, sum(par) as par from t group by id 
having sum(par) >= ALL(
select sum(par) from t group by id
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select id, s 
 from ( select id, sum(pair) as s  
          from t group by id
        order by 2 desc) 
limit 1
```