# Помогите вывести максимальное значение в SQL- запросе

Tags: sql, oracle

База СУБД Oracle. Есть три таблицы с данными. Мне надо вывести имя менеджера и максимальную сумму его сделок,в определённый период времени, если этих макс значений несколько, вывести все. Пока получилось вывести только имя и суммы сделок, просуммированные для каждого имени. Вот мой запрос

```
SELECT SALESMAN.NAME, SUM(DEAL.AMOUNTE)
FROM CUSTOMER
JOIN DEAL ON DEAL.CUSTOMER_ID = CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_ID AND DEAL.DATE_ BETWEEN '01/08/17' AND '31/08/17'
JOIN SALESMAN ON SALESMAN.SALESMAN_ID = CUSTOMER.SALESMAN_ID
GROUP BY SALESMAN.NAME;
```

Вывод в таблице

```
James Hoog  3000
Mc Lion 4500
```

Подскажите , как изменить запрос, чтобы он возвращал только максимальное значение в колонке цифр ? Пробовал делать под запрос, использовать `HAVING`, но не получается ничего. То с синтаксисом ошибка, то чего-то не хватает... Что-то самому дойти до нужного результата не получается ((

Comment: Сначала надо решить в разрезе чего надо собственно видеть суммы. и на выходе нужны все люди или только один с максимальной суммой

Comment: Mike , на выходе нужна максимальная сумма, если таких сумм несколько, то вывести надо все. К примеру Миша - 1000, Руслан - 1500 и Гена 900 , вывести надо Руслан 1500. Или Миша - 1500, Руслан - 1500 и Гена 1000. Вывести надо Миша 1500, Руслан 1500.

Comment: Посмотрите на запрос в [этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/799389/180398) Вам что-то похожее нужно, как я понял.

Comment: Нашел ответ на похожий вопрос. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/276188/sql-%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%B2-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B5 но у вас таблица несколько сложней я не соображу. Оставлю тут может кто то сможет разобраться как его под ваш вопрос сделать.

Comment: Что-то у вас противоречивые описания. Есть несколько человек, у каждого несколько сделок. Так? Вам надо вывести человека и максимальную сумму сделки, но у вас в запросе при этом `SUM(DEAL.AMOUNTE)` - это сумма сделок, а максимальная - это `max(DEAL.AMOUNTE)`. Или вам надо сначала просуммировать все сделки по каждому человеку, а потом выбрать человека, у которого сумма всех сделок наибольшая?

Comment: Dmitry, да, если у одного и того же менеджера несколько сделок, то их надо сначала просуммировать, а потом уже выводить имя менеджера и максимальную сумму, а если максимальных сумм будет несколько, то выводить все. Так же и написано в описании вверху. `SUM(DEAL.AMOUNTE)` это наверное должно быть в подзапросе, который у меня сделать и не получается.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надо посчитать суммы, пронумеровать их с помощью `rank`/`dense_rank` и выбрать первую в списке:

```
select name, summa
  from (SELECT SALESMAN.NAME, SUM(DEAL.AMOUNTE) summa,
               rank() over (order by SUM(DEAL.AMOUNTE) desc) rn
        FROM CUSTOMER
             JOIN DEAL ON DEAL.CUSTOMER_ID = CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_ID 
                      AND DEAL.DATE_ BETWEEN '01/08/17' AND '31/08/17'
             JOIN SALESMAN ON SALESMAN.SALESMAN_ID = CUSTOMER.SALESMAN_ID
        GROUP BY SALESMAN.NAME)
 where rn = 1;
```

Comment: Dmitry, скажите, а не может быть проще решение ? ))

Comment: @YuriiS Куда уж проще? ;) Не, проще не знаю.

Comment: Dmitry, спасибо за помощь ... буду разбираться ))

Comment: Dmitry, запрос работает правильно, даже не сомневался когда запускал ... но, мне думается, что должен быть вариант проще ... может с использованием псевдонимов... ищу решение дальше, но плюсик Вам поставил ))